# Set a single reminder on all week days

Tags: slack

Thanks to [Slack Help center](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/208423427-Setting-reminders#snooze-a-reminder), I'm able to set a reminder on specific days but not on all week days.

My question is: **How to set a single reminder on all week day ?**

Something like this:

> /remind @channel "It's time for daily stand up !" **Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday** at 11:45am

<s>I found a workaround but it's not really satisfying: set one reminder each day.</s>

Answer (score 291, accepted):

I found the params I missed : **`every weekday`**

Answer :

```
/remind @channel "It's time for daily stand up !" every weekday at 11:45am
```

---

**Edit :** [Slack Help Center](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/208423427-Setting-reminders) has been updated and now contains tons of reminders examples with parameters !

Comment: Is there a similar keyword for hourly reminders maybe?

Comment: Important here is the quotes - without them, Slack thinks that "every weekday" is part of the [reminder] parameter rather than part of the then [when] parameter

Comment: Is there a way to set a reminder till a particular date?  Like a recurring reminder until 12/31/2019? 
For ex: /remind me to drink water at 10.00 everyday until 12/31 ?

Comment: That sound stange (at least for french people like me) that "every weekday" would not include saturday and sunday... I was looking for every "business day" or "workdays" or "working day"... Are you sure that "every weekday" is not 7/7 ?

Comment: @pimpin I can confirm every weekday executes as Monday to Friday using slackbot but I can understand the literal translation confusion. Perhaps the bot creator didn't want to deal with handling countries where work days are not the assumed Western Monday-Friday, like in the Middle East..

Comment: Mine didn't work because I accidentally wrote the command in bold test styling. Remove all styling when doing the command.

Answer (score 44):

You can also list them:

> /remind @channel "It's time for daily stand up !" at 11:45am every
>   Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday

however if you run `/remind list`, you can find out that it is visible as simplified:

> Remind @channel “It's time for daily stand up !” at 11:45 every weekday

Comment: when I typed weekday, it decided to set it for Monday only!

Answer (score 5):

```
/remind someone to "Message" at time every weekday
```

**Note** : `Someone` can be replaced with `@channel` or `@person` or `#channel` above.